# retrieve the records from the table which contains the character or string

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

in my table some records are already stored in two columns `First_Name` and `Last_Name`.

```
Ravi Kant | Sharma

Raj  | Kumar

Ravi | Anupam

Abhinav | Kumar

Ashish | Kumar

Avinash | a

Ravi | Anand
```

And my search textbox name is `txtName`, in which i've typed `ravi`. Now, i'm using the query

```
SELECT * FROM USER_INFO 
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%"& txtName.Text &"%' 
OR LAST_NAME LIKE '%"& txtName.Text &"%'
```

So, that  it should retrieve all the record which cantains `ravi`.

But, it only return two row from the table whose First Name is `Ravi`. But, i want that it should return all the records which contains that characters, which means it must return 3 rows.

Need help !!

**EDITED**

```
"SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE (JOB_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%" & keyword.Trim() & "%' OR JOB_SKILL LIKE '%" & keyword.Trim() & "%' OR JOB_QUALIFICATION LIKE '%" & keyword.Trim() & "%') AND JOB_ROLE='" & profile & "'"
```

This is my query, where i want to use the above concept.

Comment: You're open for SQL-Injection, use SqlParameters.

Answer (score 1):

(although your solution has SQL injection  - like my friend here have said....[use Parameters])

```
var myQuery=@"SELECT * FROM USER_INFO 
    WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%"+txtName.Text.Trim() +@"%' 
    OR LAST_NAME LIKE '%"+txtName.Text.Trim() +"%'";
```

none SQlInjection ver : ( SQL SERVER SIDE)

```
SELECT * FROM USER_INFO 
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%'+@txtName +'%' 
OR LAST_NAME LIKE '%'+@txtName +'%'
```

where @`txtName` is `nvarchar(100)` // or something else...

Comment: Since this is asp.net, I believe 'txtName.Text.Trim()' would be the better choice for trimming rather than using ltrim rtrim.

Comment: still showing error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'ravi'.

Comment: @coders_zone - that's because it's missing single quotes somewhere.  Try adding the % symbols in advance like string.Format("'%{0}%'", txtName.Text.Trim())

Comment: @coders_zone - please post your entire code sample.  There's no way to troubleshoot/debug with bits and pieces.